# Inverse without compute inverse

Tags: matrices, inverse

Let's assume I have the matrices $I\in \Re^{nxn}$ which is the identity matrix and moreover both $H,B\in \Re^{nxn}$.
I want to find an alternative way to write the following espression:
$$(I+HB)^{-1}$$
Exactly I don't want to have any term in which i need to invert something where  $B$ appears.
For example i tried to use the Matrix Inversion Lemma obtaining:
$$(I+HB)^{-1}=I-IH(I+BIH)^{-1}BI=I-H(I+BH)^{-1}B$$
But as you can see in the middle term $(I+BH)^{-1}$ there is an inversion where $B$ appears.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can write it using the geometric series, at least formally:
$$(I+BH)^{-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-HB)^j,$$
but you'll definitely have some convergence issues to work out. Here, also, as a convention, $(-HB)^0:=I$.